# Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules

You guys are my last hope, I spent more than 12 hours failing to solve the problem

The application was fully functional, until I made a modification and added controls

and moved the **campground routes** to Separate file "**controlers**" to make the the router file like this

```
router.get("/", isLoggedIn, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.index));

router.get("/me", isLoggedIn, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.me));

router.get("/new", isLoggedIn, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.new_camp));

router.post("/new/submit", isLoggedIn, validate, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.submitnew));

router.get("/:id", isLoggedIn, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.show_Camp));

router.get("/:id/edit", isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.edit_Camp));

router.delete("/:id/delete", isLoggedIn, isAuthenticated, CatchAsync(Campgrounds.delete_Camp));
```

After that the application failed to run

```
Error: Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Promise]
```

here is the project on sandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-galileo-sdy0w?file=/app.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `Error` tells you everything. I saw your sandbox and it shows:

```
(alias) CatchAsync(fn: any): Promise<(req: any, res: any, next: any) => void>
```

Your `CatchAsync` function returns a promise and Route.get() needs callback.

You should realize what does `async function` mean.

From docs:

> The word “async” before a function means one simple thing: a function always returns a promise. Other values are wrapped in a resolved promise automatically.